# Хочу сменить backgroundImage с помощью classList

Tags: javascript, css

У меня есть div в котором стоит картинка как фон, и мне нужно чтобы с помощью classList менялось на другой фон. Возможно ли так сделать?

```
        <div id="div"></div>
        <button onclick="fun2()">сменить фон</button>

const div = document.getElementById("div")

function bg() {
  div.style.backgroundImage = "url(image.jpg)";
}
bg();

function fun2() {
  div.classList.add("bg2");
}

.bg2 { background-image: url("image2.jpg");
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос и проблема?...

Comment: `Возможно ли так сделать?`- Да.

Comment: ``!important``?

Comment: @МихаилРебров, проблема в том, что у inline-стиля приоритет выше.